# Retriving field value

Tags: entities

I have field called field_3d_model_xml_path which is a text type. I am currently retriving the value like this.

```
//get current node
$node = menu_get_object();
//build xml path
$xmlPath = DRUPAL_ROOT . "/" . $node->field_3d_model_xml_path['und'][0]['value'];
```

Is this right way to do it or there is some better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way is to use [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) like this (which will handle any languages):

```
$xmlPath = '';
if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_3d_model_xml_path')) {
  $xmlPath = $items[0]['value'];
}
```

If you want to access it like you currently are (sometimes it is useful to do so but in your case I don't think so, this is just to be more complete), use the [LANGUAGE_NONE](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_NONE/7) constant for the 'und' language instead of hard coding it, like this:

```
$xmlPath = DRUPAL_ROOT . "/" . $node->field_3d_model_xml_path[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```